LlamaParse not able to parse documents inside directory
Whenever I try to use LlamaParse I get an error that states the file_input must be a file path string, file bytes, or buffer object.
parser = LlamaParse(result_type="markdown")
file_extractor = {'.pdf': parser}

reader = SimpleDirectoryReader(input_dir = './data', file_extractor=file_extractor,recursive=True).load_data()

The full error: Error while parsing the file '<bytes/buffer>': file_input must be either a file path string, file bytes, or buffer object
Empty Response
This is how my folder structure looks like
I tried using the SimpleDirectoryReader without the file_extractor to see if the issue is in the SimpleDirectoryReader method, which worked without using that parameter. So the issue is caused by LlamaParse.

I have recently had the same issue with LlamaParse, and here's the only solution that comes to my mind:
from llama_parse.base import ResultType, Language

parser = LlamaParse(result_type=ResultType.MD,language=Language.ENGLISH)
pdf_data = parser.load_data('{full_address}/app/data/Introduction-to-Insects.pdf')

Also, you don't really need recursive=True as far as you don't have subdirectories.
